# Angular/Rxjs pipe async does not work with ssr?

Tags: angular, rxjs, nestjs, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an issue with the async pipe running on SSR. there are no errors, only an infinite loop (it seems that the server is waiting for the observable to be resolved).

I am using:

1. @nestjs/ng-universal
2. Angular 9
3. Firebase
4. Rxjs

A simple case like this works:

```
<p>{{ observable | async }}</p>
```

But using structural directives do not work:

**ngIf**

```
<p *ngIf="(observable$ | async) > 5">{{ observable$ | async }}</p>
```

**Ngfor**

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{ item }}</p>
```

Using async is a good practice because it will avoid manual unsubscribe to avoid memory leak when the component is destroyed. However, using manual unsubscribe works.

**Update 08/06/2020**

When I add the index.html after http://localhost:4200 the app loads

The async is in the template like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currentUser$ | async; else loadingUser">
```

and currentUser$ is set in the `ngOnInit` method of the component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUser$ = this.authService.currentUser$;
  }
```

**Update 16/06/2020**

When we remove ALL uses of OnPush detection strategy in components, then SSR mode works, even with async used in structural directives.

So this seems to indicate that using OnPush TOGETHER with async in structural directives does not work in SSR mode.

**Note**

We are using `nest.js` for SSR/Universal.

Comment: Where in your component are you defining the observable?

Comment: Note this user had a similar issue where it only loaded by adding index.html to the url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924369/angular-ssr-localhost-4000-does-not-open

Comment: @SantiBarbat I updated the question with the info (I'm on the same team as the OP)

Comment: We just hit this as well. Feel like this is an issue we should report it to angular

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation for why OnPush and the async pipe don't work together in SSR? Or did you report an issue to angular? Unfortunately I'm facing the same issue and can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

When we use OnPush change detection strategy we basically detect the changes when we specifically want it.

OnPush change is only detected when we change the reference of the variable and not just the value.

So here your both the concepts are getting conflicted. Either you change your detection strategy or you change the reference of the **currentUser$** observable.

I would suggest you should change the detection strategy here.

Comment: Thanks but I understand how change detection works, both default and OnPush. We did change the detection strategy to default (ie. automatic) and then SSR mode works. But with OnPush and the async pipe in the same project, SSR mode does not work.