# Spartacus Lazy loading of CMS components makes application flickers in SSR mode

Tags: angular, angular-universal, spartacus-storefront

I tried to make **Lazy Loading of CMS Components**,
But am getting below error:

**ERROR Error: The pipe 'async' could not be found!**

**It works fine with CSR, but with SSR it is not working.**

I have **Spartacus 3.4** and **Angular 10.2.3** in my application.

I tried the fix given by Jerry here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68403755/1606761

Above fix makes flicker issue in SSR.

Below is my code sample,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomProductListGuard } from './custom-product-list.guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ConfigModule.withConfig(<CmsConfig>{
      cmsComponents: {
        CMSProductListComponent: {
          component: () => import('./container/custom-product-list.component').then(m => m.CustomProductListComponent),
          guards: [CustomProductListGuard]
        }
      },
    }),
  ]
})
export class CustomProductListModule {
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with SSR flickering with a user logged in have come up before. Have you tried enabling transfer state?

Here are some more in-depth recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883085/12566149